# Lightbox in Latex

Tags: hyperref

Is there a package or simple code for a [lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29) in LaTeX? (I'd like to display the solutions of some math problems in a clever way.)

Could `hyperref` be used to prompt a small pdf or jpeg and have it be overlaid on the original pdf document (without the lightbox effect)?

Comment: For the second cuestion , the [fancytooltips](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) or [cooltooltips](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cooltooltips) packages could be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [fancytooltips](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) of [cooltooltips](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cooltooltips) could be useful. A little example using `fancytooltips`:

First you need to create a `.pdf` file containing the `\keytips` commands (one `\keytip` per page) and the text for the tooltips that will be used by the `fancytooltips` package. To create this `.pdf` document you can use LaTeX: in this example I used a file (called `soltips.tex`) having the following aspect

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{framed}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!70!black}

\begin{document}

\keytip{factorx}
\begin{shaded}
\begin{align*}
  8x^2 - 32 &= 8(x^2 - 4) \\
  &= 8(x - 2)(x + 2).
\end{align*}
\end{shaded}

\newpage

\keytip{factora}
\begin{shaded}
\begin{align*}
  a^2 + 8a + 16 &=  a^2 + 8a + 4^2 \\
  &= (a + 4)(a + 4) \\
  &= (a + 4)^2.
\end{align*}
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

Compile this file in the standard way to generate the file `soltips.pdf` containing the solutions, one on each page, nicely shaded, and with their corresponding `\keytip` command. The resulting `.pdf` file has to be in the same directory containing your main `.tex` file (the one containing the problems).

Now, your main document containing the problems has to be something like the following (note that the value for the filename key is exactly the name of the `.pdf` file obtained in the previous step):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[filename=soltips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\begin{prob}
Factor $8x^2 - 32$.
\end{prob}
\noindent\tooltip{Solution}{factorx}

\begin{prob}
Factor $ax^2 + 8a + 16$.
\end{prob}
\noindent\tooltip{Solution}{factora}

\end{document}
```

Compile this file in the standard way and you'll see your solutions with a blue balloon; if you move the mouse pointer to the active area, a tooltip will open displaying the corresponding answer.

**Some remarks:**

1) Of course, you can obtain fancyer tooltips by changing the aspect of the solutions in the file `soltips.pdf`.

2) This approach doesn't work in all PDF viewers, since it requires cooperation with JavaScripts; you have to use Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat to see the tooltips.